# Why there is a の in オープンしたばかりのレストラン?

Tags: grammar, particle-の

I learned that in Japanese you can put a sentence in front of a noun without の: like "買った本" or "もらったプレゼント".

In a JLPT N3 sample question I encountered "オープンしたばかりのレストラン". Could I omit the の and just say "オープンしたばかりレストラン"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you're modifying a noun with a verb phrase (e.g., 美智子が買った本), no particle is used between the verb phrase and the modified noun. However, ばかり acts like a noun, and when you're modifying a noun with a noun phrase in Japanese, the の particle is required. If it's helpful, think of オープンしたばかりのレストラン as the same construction as:

> 美智子が買った本のブックカバー

Whether ばかり is *actually* a noun is an interesting question. (It seems to me that it is, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: I am aware that noun + の + noun. However, according to jisho.org, ばかり is a particle. And オープンしたばかり seems to be a complete sentence to me. So after your explanation my confusion still stands.

Comment: オープンしたばかり is a complete sentence only in the sense that you can drop the だ from the end of a sentence and have it still sound natural in some contexts. I'd say ばかり is an adverbial noun like 場合; it operates like a noun and requires の to modify a noun. There really isn't more to it than that, I'm afraid. It's not a verb and can't directly modify a noun the way a verb phrase or い-adjective can.

Comment: I've never heard ばかり defined as a particle...

Comment: @istrasci If you check just about any monolingual dictionary, you'll find it listed as a 副助詞, and then you will have heard of it.